# Custom PipelineDB extension

Tags: pipelinedb

Currently I can see support for kafka and kinesis, is it possible to add custom protocol extension to pipelinedb ? If yes, where can I find some guidelines to write it.

-
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PostgreSQL extension interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/extend-extensions.html) to write PipelineDB extensions.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Please share some sample if you can.

Comment: Our own [pipeline_kafka](https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipeline_kafka) extension is a pretty thorough reference.